# Tangent space of $G \times_H M$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, equivalence-relations, tangent-spaces

Let $G$ be a Lie group and let $H$ be a Lie subgroup of $G$. Let $M$ be a smooth manifold on which $H$ acts from the left.

Let's consider the  action of  $H$ on $G \times M$ : $$h((g,m)):= (gh,h^{-1}m), \quad h \in H , g \in G , m \in M, $$ and define the manifold $Z$ to be  the quotient $G  \times_H M .$

I'm reading some lecture notes and I'm stuck to understand the following statement in it:

> The tangent space $ T_{[g,m]} Z$ is identified with $T_gG \times T_m M/\sim, $ where  $\sim$ is the relation of equivalence coming from the $H$ -orbits in $G \times M.$

Can someone please explain this identification.

Ps. My thoughts about this was to use the fact that $G \times_H M \rightarrow G/H$ is a fiber bundle and use local trivialization to identify $T_{[g,m]}Z$ with $T_mM \times T_{[g]}(G/H)$, but I don't know how to obtain the identification in the lecture notes.

Comment: Why don't you start by editing your post to write down the equivalence relation which defines $G\times_H M$ in the first place. Surely the statement is just immediate from that.

Comment: Thanks Ted Shifting. I've edited my question.

Comment: So what is the induced action of $h$ on $T_g G\times T_mM$?

Comment: If the action of $h \in H$ fixes (g,m) ,i e $h.(g,m)=(g,m)$, then  I would say the action of $h$ on $ T_gG \times T_m M$ is coming from the derivative of the action of $h$ on $G \times M$. If not, I don't know what is the induced action in this case.

Comment: Sorry, I spoke sloppily. If you fix $(v,w)\in T_gG\times T_mM$, what is its induced $H$-orbit under the derivative?

Comment: If we denote $a_h$ the action of $h$ on $G$, and $b_h$ the action of $h$ on $M$, then the $H$ orbit of $(v,w) $ is the set $\mathcal{O}_{(v,w)}=\lbrace {(da_h(v),db_{h^{-1}}(w),)h∈H} \rbrace$.

Comment: Something is off here.  The action of $H$ on $G$ is free, so the only reasonable induced action of $H$ on $T_g G\times T_m M$ is the trivial action.  Did you possibly mean $T_{[g,m]}$ is identified with $TG\times TM/\sim$?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jason DeVito. I've checked  the lecture notes, it says $T_{[g,m]}Z$ is identified with $T_gG \times T_mM / \sim .$